# Running unit tests with chutzpah on real browser

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, chutzpah

Is there a way to setup Chutzpah to run test with other browser than phantomjs, preferably real browser, not headless.

I'm using chutzpah as Visual Studio extension and runner 4.2.1 for CI

Please let me know if more information needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today you can use the OpenInBrowser command and chutzpah will open the harness in a real browser. I am also working on supporting headless chrome but not sure when it will be ready.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Comment: hey @matthew-manela , just last one question, do you know how to get console logs? 
after: 
    chutzpah.console.exe chutzpah.json /openInBrowser firefox`
all tests and files get loaded properly, but logs are in browser.
I switch tests to run from slimerjs and I can see result but still no logs... wich means with CI it will not work
with phantomjs I can see output from chutzpah in console, but phantom dosn't support loading as I need.

Comment: Correct, right now if you choose openinbrowser it *only* runs in that browser and does not run locally in the client.